# Regex to match 1 to 4 digits proceeded by many zeros or white space

Tags: c#, regex

I've made a pattern

```
([0-9]{1,4})(?<=[0\s]*)
```

It [doesn't achieve what I want](https://regexr.com/4617k), it is too greedy. Essentially, I want to find the last 4 digits.

Given the test data, I would like these matches:

```
12          -> 12
0123        -> 0123
1230        -> 1230
1234        -> 1234
 12         -> 12
 0123       -> 0123
 1230       -> 1230
 1234       -> 1234
 0123       -> 0123
000123      -> 0123
001230      -> 1230
001234      -> 1234
 000123     -> 0123
 001230     -> 1230
 001234     -> 1234
 000123     -> 0123
 0123       -> 0123
a11230      -> 1230
a11234      -> 1234
 a10123     -> 0123
 a11230     -> 1230
 a11234     -> 1234
 a10123     -> 0123
```

What is the "best" pattern to achieve that result?

Best being short and easy to comprehend unless there is some good, expressible reason for an alternative.

Comment: Won't `[0-9]{1,4}\b` do? Or `[0-9]{1,4}(?!\S)` if you need a whitespace boundary on the right?

Comment: Why are you using a lookbehind *after* a pattern? If at all you want to use it at the start (or in some combinations with alternatives which you don't have here).

Comment: I checked and [it seems it works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c4%7d%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=12%0d%0a0123%0d%0a1230%0d%0a1234%0d%0a+12%0d%0a+0123%0d%0a+1230%0d%0a+1234%0d%0a+0123%0d%0a000123%0d%0a001230%0d%0a001234%0d%0a+000123%0d%0a+001230%0d%0a+001234%0d%0a+000123%0d%0a+0123%0d%0aa11230%0d%0aa11234%0d%0a+a10123%0d%0a+a11230%0d%0a+a11234%0d%0a+a10123)

Comment: A list of things you want is not a question; what's your question?

Comment: @EricLippert I added a question.

Comment: Just replace leading zeroes : 0{2,+}\d+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\d{1,4}(?!\S)
```

Example, https://regex101.com/r/Lk328i/3

Comment: I'm happy to take the down votes on the question but could anyone explain why this might be a bad answer?

Comment: @Jodrell am curious as well.